# Can you share a SQL Server session between a Web Forms app and a Asp.NET Core MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

We have an ASP.net Web Forms application running on the .NET 4.61 framework, and an Asp.NET Core application running on the same .NET 4.61 framework.

The Web Forms application uses a session cookie and SQL Server to store the session information.

Is there a way to configure the Asp.NET Core application to read and use that session data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not possible to share session state between ASP.NET apps and ASP.NET Core apps. This is because of two main reasons:

1. ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core handle session stores differently. In ASP.NET, you had session providers, whereas in ASP.NET Core, it uses `IDistributedCache` for session sate. While you can use something like SQL Server for both, the mechanism of actually storing the state is not the same in each case, and therefore, one couldn't read what the other is doing.
2. Session data is encrypted and the mechanism of encryption in ASP.NET is different from that of ASP.NET Core. In ASP.NET, the machine key is used to encrypt/decrypt, but in ASP.NET Core, there is no concept of a machine key. Instead, ASP.NET Core uses an instance of `IDataProtectionProvider` to encrypt/decrypt. As a result, even if you could get both to see the same session store *and* be able to read it, neither would be capable of decrypting the data stored by the other.